# Send Mail to Specific Roles

Tags: routes, rules

I need to send Emails to site users with specific role like "Administrator".

This is achievable using view on any action like "After saving new content".. etc..

But i want to send emails on one menu click event, I have menu item in Management Menu of Drupal and on click of that i want to send mails to all admin users.

How this is achievable?? Please suggest me guys..

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

With custom module.
See [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

As page_callback define your "send mail" function for restricted user roles

Comment: I know this but how can i achieve this using rules as i have to pass message body, subject and other parameters from token..

Comment: Create rule on Event: System->init and then check for url as condition and add custom php as result

Comment: Thanks.. but is it possible to add default value of field as replacement pattern..??

Comment: if you can add a field value then this field should evaluate to default value if no other value was defined for that field